# AuthorizeAttribute in WCF as MVC's

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm new to WCF (Most of my time, I worked with ASP.NET Web API & MVC).

I wonder there is any AuthorizeAttribute in WCF or not (custom implementation is ok) .

For example:

+) In Web API, I have these steps :

-) Call [POST] api/login with email & password to login

-) Store email & password in front-end site, each time front-end sends a request, they have to include email & password in header for authentication.

-) In back-end, AuthorizeAttribute reads email & password of request header, do validation then authenticate the request as it is valid.

My question is:
Can my WCF application have an Attribute to do the same work as the API does ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your custom [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class MyValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string user, string password)
    {
        // Do your validation logic.
        // In case of unauthorized access throw appropriate exception.
    }
}
```

And configure service behavior to use it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="behavior_name">
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                        customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SomeNamespace.MyValidator, AssemblyName" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Also it is not a good idea to store password. Would be better to generate an auth token by this login & password, and use that token.

Comment: What if I only want to apply the authentication for some methods. I.e: FindAccount(string name), FindPlace(string name) but Login(userName, password)

Comment: @Redplane Then you need to implement whole custom authentication with identities, claims and so on. You can start with [this article](http://www.developerhandbook.com/wcf/wcf-custom-authentication-using-servicecredentials/) (best I could find when I started on custom WCF auth task) and [this repo](https://github.com/jpreecedev/WCFCustomServiceCredentials) (code from article). But as I followed that I stumbled upon on a [strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176845/how-to-pass-claims-from-custom-iauthorizationpolicy-to-current-servicesecurityco) and still have no solution.

Comment: @Redplane however thinking of wcf as of asp.net mvc is incorrect. Wcf is more like you just create a local instance of a class and invoke it's methods. So, if you need to authorize users for separate methods you can either write a custom code or use CAS (Code Access Security, for example, decorate methods with [`PrincipalPermissionAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: @Redplane by the way, you can take a look at [ASP.NET WebAPI](https://www.asp.net/web-api). It's design is much closer to asp.net mvc then wcf's design. MSDN: [WCF and ASP.NET Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx).